# How should I pass arguments to a function using in Python (dict vs variables)?

Tags: python, function, parameters, arguments

I have a function/method `A()` which expects some arguments (including optional arguments). Another function `B()` does the pre-processing on the data to be passed to the said function `A()`. I have few alternate implementation of the function `B()` which is causing me confusion regarding the advantages of one over the another.
I would like to understand which among them(if any) should I use.

After all, `There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.`

Here is the code snippet:

```
class Foo(object):

    def __init__(self, param1, param2, param3=None):
        self.param1 = param1
        self.param2 = param2
        self.param3 = param3

    @classmethod
    def from_dump_v1(cls, dump):
        param1, param2, param3 = dump.get('param_1'), dump.get('_param_2'), dump.get('paramThree')
        return cls(param1, param2, param3)

    @classmethod
    def from_dump_v2(cls, dump):
        dump['param1'] = dump.pop('param_1')
        dump['param2'] = dump.pop('_param_2')
        dump['param3'] = dump.pop('paramThree')
        return cls(**dump)

    @classmethod
    def from_dump_v3(cls, dump):
        result = dict()
        result['param1'] = dump.get('param_1')
        result['param2'] = dump.get('_param_2')
        result['param3'] = dump.get('paramThree')
        return cls(**result)
```

In the above code, `__init__` refers to `A()` and `from_dump_v*` represent the different implementations I need to chose from.
NOTE: In all the cases the `dump` is a dictionary with 3 key-value pairs, namely `param_1`, `_param_2` and `paramThree`.

Comment: Sorry for over simplifying my question here.
I have updated the question with more realistic requirements.

Answer (score 7):

One *obvious way* to do this could be:

```
@classmethod
def from_dump_v(cls, dump):
    return cls(**{k.replace('_', ''): v for k, v in dump.items()})
```

---

In the case the `dump` dict holds arbitrary keys, I can't see the *one obvious way* to do this; I'm not dutch.

However, with some control over the argument of the factory function, you can change the data type to a sequence instead of a dict, and then do something obvious with `enumerate`:

```
@classmethod
def from_dump_v(cls, dump):
    return cls(**{"param{}".format(i): x for i, x in enumerate(dump, 1)})
```

Comment: But I may not always want to replace `_`.

Comment: @KshitijSaraogi well then, you can write a function to transform the key in whatever way you need and use that in the dictionary comprehension. Or you could expand your example so we can examine and address the other possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are making a factory function to handle your class initialization. So, to make that happen, you can use `*args` and `**kwargs` to pass any number of arguments (parameters and keyword arguments) to your factory function. But it seems redundant.

Hence, you can have something like this:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, param1, param2, param3=None):
        self.param1 = param1
        self.param2 = param2
        self.param3 = param3

    @classmethod
    def from_dump_vx(cls, *args, **kwargs):
      return cls(*args, **kwargs)
```

In `from_dump_vx`, you can process the values in `*args` and `**kwargs` to your preference and then pass them to your class's `__init__` method.

Then you can initialize your class like this:

```
y = Foo.from_dump_vx(1, 2, param3=3)
```